# Custom data types in JDBCTemplate

Tags: postgresql, jdbctemplate

How to deal with the custom data type with JDBCTemplate?

For example, when using postgres jdbc library, there is a method [addDataType](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/PGConnection.html#addDataType-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) which can be used to add user defined types.

However I wonder how to implement this when using `JDBCTemplate` since I try to avoid using the low level `connection`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

After wake up, I suddeny noticed that what I need in fact is a hook for the `connection` object, maybe I can do this by extends the `DataSource` and override the `getConnection()` method.

Before:

```
mDataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
mJdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(mDataSource);
```

After:

```
mDataSource = new CustomDataTypeDataSource(config);
mJdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(mDataSource);

class CustomDataTypeDataSource extends HikariDataSource {
    public CustomDataTypeDataSource() {
        super();
    }

    public CustomDataTypeDataSource(HikariConfig configuration) {
        super(configuration);
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = super.getConnection();
        prepareConnection(conn); 
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Then we can do all the magic(add the custom data type) in `prepareConnection()` (PostgreSQL in my case):

```
@Override
protected void prepareConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    if (connection != null) {
        PgConnection pgconn = ((PgConnection) connection.unwrap(PGConnection.class));
        pgconn.addDataType("xx", xx.class);
    }
}
```